# Solve the system of equations: $32y+32x^3=6x+17$, $16z+32y^3=6y+9$, $8x+32z^3=6z+5$ where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

Solve the system of equations: $$\begin{cases} 32y+32x^3=6x+17 \\16z+32y^3=6y+9 \\8x+32z^3=6z+5 \end{cases}$$ where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ (Bulgaria 1960)

I attempted to solve this question as follows:

$32y+32x^3=6x+17$

$y=-x^3+\frac{6x}{32}+\frac{17}{32}$

$y-\frac{1}{2}=-x^3+\frac{3x}{16}+\frac{17}{32}-\frac{1}{2}$

Here it started getting very complex, and hence I don't think it can be solved this way. After this I tried doing something similar with the other two equations, but once again it was ending up way too complex. It is obvious that the solution is $x=y=z=\frac{1}{2}$, but I can't manage to prove it. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: It is always possible to bring the system of equations to any degree of polynomial.  The important thing here is to find the smartest way.

Comment: @lonestudent. It is just a polynomial of degree $27$ is $x$ !

Comment: It's better to make a change of variable $(x',y',z') = (2x,2y,2z)$.

Comment: @NN2. Could you explain why ? Not knowing the result for sure. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, you are right :) actually, if it was a low degree polynomial, all students would solve the problem :) I wish I had time to look at problem..  But I will probably wait for the smart answers given :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This transformation makes the equation system clearer.

Comment: Your equations looked bad.  I edited your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for simplicity's sake, make a change of variables $$(a,b,c) = (2x,2y,2z)$$
We have the system of equations
\begin{align}
16b + 4a^3 &= 3a+17 \\
8c + 4b^3 &= 3b+9 \\
4a + 4c^3 &= 3c+5 \\
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
16(b-1)  &= - 4a^3+3a+1 \\
8(c-1)   &= - 4b^3+3b+1 \\
4(a-1)  &=-4c^3+ 3c+1 \\
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
16(b-1)  &= - (a-1)(4a^2+4a+1) \tag{1}\\
8(c-1)   &= - (b-1)(4b^2+4b+1) \tag{2}\\
4(a-1)  &=-(c-1)(4c^2+4c+1) \tag{3}\\
\end{align}

Suppose $b >1$ then from $(1)$: $a<1$ $\implies$ from $(3)$: $c>1$ $\implies$ from $(2)$: $b>1$  $\implies$ contracdiction!

Same for  $b <1$, we have also a contradiction.

For $b=1$, we have $c =1$ and $a =1$.

**Conclusion:** the system of equations has a unique solution $(a,b,c) = (1,1,1)$ or $$(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

Comment: +1. Nice solution. Minor nitpick : I would have written this way: if one of $(a,b,c)$ is $1$ then others are $1$. If none of them is $1$, then multiplying eqns $1,2,3$, we see there is no other real solution.

Comment: suggestion  instead of taking cases multiplying $$(1)\times (2)\times (3)\to  (a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(16\cdot 8\cdot 4+4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3)=0$$  whcih $\implies$ atleast one of $a,b,c=1$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yes, It's really a better approach.

Comment: @NN2 thanks! thats what even cosmo5 said except that my comment was seconds later

Comment: I don't get it how you canceled the square terms, to get (1): $$(a-1)(4a^2+1)=4a^3-4a^2+a-1\ne 4a^3-3a-1$$

Comment: @Andrei good point,NN2 I have edited your post as I felt you made a typo , please recheck

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thank you! :)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore you are canceling the linear term, not the quadratic. It should be $4a^2+4a+1$

Comment: @Andrei Yes, I modified. The idea is to factorize $-4a^3+3a+1 = -(a-1)(4a^2+4a+1)=-(a-1)(a+1)^2$. The second term is positive.

Comment: Indeed, (2a+1)^2 is always positive, or zero at $a=-1/2$. That is easily treated as a separate case.

Comment: @Andrei: We don't need to treat the case $ a = -1/2$ as a separated case. Just arguing as I did: if $b>1 \implies a<1 \implies  c>1 \implies b<1 ...$

Answer (score 2):

## Proof by Contradiction:

Let,  $32x^3-6x>1$  then:

$$\begin{align} 32x^3-6x>1 &\Longrightarrow x>\frac 12\\ 32x^3-6x=17-32y>1 &\Longrightarrow y<\frac 12 \\32y^3-6y=9-16z <1 &\Longrightarrow z>\frac 13\\ 2z^3-6z=5-8x >1 &\Longrightarrow x<\frac 12\end{align}$$ which gives a contradiction.

The same method also works for $32x^3-6x<1$. We obtain again a contradiction.

So, we deduce that $$\begin{align} 17-32y=32x^3-6x=1
&\Longrightarrow y=\frac 12 \\ 9-16z=32y^3-6y 
&\Longrightarrow z=\frac 12\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} x=\frac {6z+5-32z^3}{8}=\frac{4}{8}=\frac 12\end{align}$$

Finally, our real solutions are only $$x=y=z=\dfrac 12.$$

---

I used :

- If $32x^3-6x>1$, then $x>\frac 12$. Because,

$$\begin{align}32x^3-6x-1&=32\left(x+\frac 14\right)^2\left(x-\frac 12\right)>0.&\end{align}$$

- If $y<\frac 12$, then $32y^3-6y<1$. Because,

$$\begin{align}32y^3-6y-1&=32\left(y+\frac 14\right)^2\left(y-\frac 12\right)<0.&\end{align}$$

- If $z>\frac 12$, then $32z^3-6z>1$. Because,

$$\begin{align}32z^3-6z-1&=32\left(z+\frac 14\right)^2\left(z-\frac 12\right)>0.&\end{align}$$